# First connection to Mongo Atlas takes a long time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, prisma

I'm using Mongo Atlas with Prisma. Whenever I launch my project, it takes about 3 minutes for database to connect, and in this period of time, I can't see anything in Mongo Atlas' connection tab. I've tried Prisma's logger, no error prints at all. Interestingly, it connects but it just takes time.

It eventually connects, but this issue with connection time makes using hot reload quite hard. I've tried allowing incoming Node apps in Advanced Firewall Settings, and my firewall is disabled. Actually I couldn't find a lot of people experiencing this, so I couldn't try much to be honest. And to note, when somebody else tries to launch exact same code, their database starts working instantly.

Comment: To get the idea, do you have ensure index enabled? How many collections do you have? Size of data?

Comment: Two of my friends tried exact same code and their database worked instantly, so I don't think this is about sizes or indexes.

Comment: Could it just be a slow internet issue? I would try connecting to the atlas instance with something else, like the MongoDB nodejs driver or MongoDB compass and see how long that takes.

Comment: I have 200 Mbps download speed.

Comment: I see. Does this also happen if you try to connect to your atlas instance through something other than Prisma (like the Node.js driver)?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.

Comment: I see, I'd definitely consider reaching out to Atlas support in that case. It might be something from their side.